# Voice to text transfer in apex input text field in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, html

I have a requirement to create a visualforce Page where voice will be transformed to text and search records.

Can someone please let me know if that can be possible? If yes, please let me have some definite link to do so.

I have tried this, but it is not working for me. Even if I speak it is unable to capture it in text box.

https://github.com/vishnuvaishnav/Voice-Recognition-Search-in-Salesforce-VF-Page-/blob/master/VoiceRecognition.page

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Voice to text and text to voice is implemented in the browser using the Aria standards (tags used to describe media on HTML pages).

The search itself would be done using Standard or Custom Search features via SOSL. In essence, all of the voice translation is done outside of Salesforce in the browser using tools for the visually impaired or add-ons like Dragon Naturally Speaking. Its beyond what you can expect Apex to do. There's a Trailhead Module that covers Salesforce Search capabilities.